# joining two tables in SQL based on one common value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables in my SQL database. I need to create a report that would show me the strStoredAcctID based on lngItemID that I enter. When the search is performed I only know the 41139320 number. I don't know how to combine the two queries based on the information I have.  Here's the query I used.

```
SELECT  tblItem.lngItemID, tblItem.lngEntitleItemIDRef
FROM tblItem   
WHERE   tblItem.lngEntitleItemIDRef = 41139320  

SELECT tblStoredValue.lngItemID, tblStoredValue.strStoredAcctID
FROM tblStoredValue
WHERE tblStoredValue.lngItemID = 41886227
```

Instead of running two, I would like to be able to type in the lngItemID = 41139320 only and receive the strStoredAcctID. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: queries and tables]

Comment: if you tighten up your query, you might be able to get way with a simple union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses the result set of the first query to filter the data of the referencing query, this is called a subquery - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT tblStoredValue.lngItemID, tblStoredValue.strStoredAcctID 
FROM tblStoredValue 
WHERE tblStoredValue.lngItemID IN (
    SELECT tblItem.lngItemID
    FROM tblItem
    WHERE tblItem.lngEntitleItemIDRef = 41139320
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why a simple `INNER JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` won't work?

Comment: No ```GROUP BY``` because I'm not sure of the first queries results could have multiple corresponding results for the next query. @devlincarnate Happy for you to show me how you would do it?

Comment: Thank you! I received the following error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: Thats fixed now, apologies! try again

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT tblStoredValue.strStoredAcctID FROM tblItem
LEFT JOIN tblStoredValue on tblItem.lngItemID=tblStoredValue.lngItemID
WHERE tblItem.lngEntitleItemIDRef = 41139320
```

Comment: The OP states the desired result is to only get `strStoredAcctID`.

Comment: Easily fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tblStoredValue.strAcctID
FROM tblItem
INNER JOIN tblStoredValue ON tblStoredValue.lgnItemID = tblItem.lgnItemID
WHERE tblItem.lgnEntitleItemIDRef = 41139320
```

Comment: Thank you! I do get two records when I run the query. One with the strStoredAcctID and the other is NULL. It's honestly fine and I can live with it.